# Is there some Wiki markup for "back" in SharePoint's Wiki?

Tags: navigation, wiki, quick-launch, markup

At our organization, we've buried our SP installation in the bowels of our corporate intranet front-end, so it's always completely non-intutive to find. I've created a "How to get to SharePoint" tutorial as part of a documentation wiki, but here's what I'm running into:

There are dozens of pathways to get to "How to Get to Sharepoint", but no automated way to go BACK from whence I came. Ideally, we'd like a link to the referring page as the "next step" in the process, after someone reads how to get to SharePoint.

Is there something like this that's out there?

We're running SP2010 Foundation, and our area does not have access to Designer or development resources. :|

Comment: Denis' answer worked for me and stayed within the confines of the Wiki code. I just had to replace "Previous Page Name" with my pages previous page name. Since I only get to this page from one other page, unless someone gets here from a search, then I know what the previous page name is and it looks like this "[[Scripts and Batch Files|Back]]" Thanks for the help. Makes perfect sense, now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can drop a Content Editor web part into the page you can add an anchor and some javascript into the web part that looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:history.length&gt;0?history.back(): window.location = &#39;http://yoursitehere.com&#39;;">Go back to previous page.</a>
```

Just replace "yoursitehere.com" with your own site page URL and it ought to work.

To break that out, it looks like this:

```
if(history.length > 0)
{
    history.back()
} else window.location = "http://mainpageofthesite.com"
```

I believe SharePoint actually converted the greater than and quote symbols for me, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Nice and simple. It should be marked accepted.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use the own wiki structure to avoid break links.

```
[[Previous Page Name| Back]]
```